# Cygwin terminal prompt missing

Tags: shell, cygwin

Previously, when launching the Cygwin terminal, a console will popup and the line will say:
`username@PCName ~` then a blinking cursor after `$`.

Now a blank console appears and nothing is on the console screen but a blinking cursor...

The shortcut seem to be directing to the right path "C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -" so I don't know what's going on.

How do I go about fixing this issue? Do I have to look into the Environment variables? If so what do I have to look for?

I'm running Windows XP Professional x86.

Comment: Does it start up successfully if you launch from the plain old Cygwin terminal (or run `cygwin.bat` from a cmd.exe session) instead of Mintty?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that as substitute at the moment... however whenever I make a mistake and press backspace, it doesn't backspace but forward spaces... -_- kinda frustrating.

Comment: Here's how to fix the backspace issue: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-04/msg01062.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say it starts up successfully using `cmd`, it could a problem starting up you mintty environment. Try going into your home directory and deleting (back it up somewhere else if you want to be able to bring it back) the `.minttyrc` file and then try to start up again.

If that doesn't do the trick, try to go a little bigger and do the same with the bash environment files. Back up `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.bash_aliases` (if you have it) and `.inputrc` and replace them with the default sample files that are in the `/etc/skel` folder, then try to restart again.

Comment: It seemed like what you linked me "cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-04/msg01062.html" did the trick. After I removed the MKS variables in the environment variables... Cygwin is working properly again! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the shorcut to this:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash -l
```